# Error response from API call using Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to make a call to the API and the error response comes in two ways.

First is like this (where the message is an object with multiple string lists)

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": {
    "email": [
        "Must be between 2 and 20 characters."
    ],
    "password": [
        "Must be between 2 and 25 characters."
    ]
  }
}
```

And the other is like this (where message is just a string)

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "User with that email exists."
}
```

My model so far looks like this:

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("success")
    private boolean success;


    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    private Message message;

    //constructor & getters & setters

    public class Message {

        @Expose
        @SerializedName("email")
        private List<String> email;

        @Expose
        @SerializedName("password")
        private List<String> password;

        //constructor & getters & setters
    }
}
```

How can I treat both cases of "message" in model class?

Comment: that is kind of wrong response architecture. It is bad to use different types for the same field in JSON

Comment: @anMC you need to change the response architecture and if you need to validate above two field the it can be validate from android side also using length(size) of the email OR password character.

Comment: @anMC how many fields do you want to validate? if you have only above two fields want to validate than i already said that using length you can achive it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to have a `ErrorMessage` property and by **success** flag handle presentation in client.

Answer (score 0):

If this two pattern are fix then you can try below way :

**ErrorResponse.java**

```
public class ErrorResponse {

@Expose
@SerializedName("success")
private boolean success;


@Expose
@SerializedName("message")
private MyMessage message;

public class MyMessage{

 private Message message;

 private String StrMessage;

}

//constructor & getters & setters

public class Message {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("email")
    private List<String> email;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("password")
    private List<String> password;

    //constructor & getters & setters
}
}
```

And when you want to use their value just check which kind of value it is like below.

```
if(StrMessage!=null){
//Message is string.
}
else{
//do your stuff. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your JSON manually, For example if your JSON has `message` and your `message` has email tag then using the second model and if not using the first model, it works only if you have this two kind of messages.

something like this using Gson:

```
JsonElement rootTree = parser.parse(jsonRequest);
        if (rootTree.isJsonObject()) {

         JsonObject object = rootTree.getAsJsonObject();
         JsonElement message= object.get("message");

         if(message.isJsonObject()) {
                JsonElement email = message.get("email");

                if(email != null) {
                          //Use second model
                } else {
                          //Use first model                     
                }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        if (json.has("message")) {
            if (json.get("message") instanceof String) {
                message = json.getString("message");
            } else if (json.get("message") instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject("message");
                if (jsonObject.has("email")) {
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("email");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        email.add(array.getString(i));
                    }
                }
                if (jsonObject.has("password")) {
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("password");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        password.add(array.getString(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to handle JSONException.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It is working for me. and it's a easiest way to handle this kind of response.

API request using ResponseBody,

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = .......

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                try {
                    if (response.body() != null && response.body().string() != null) {

                        Object json = new JSONTokener(response.toString()).nextValue();

                        if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
                            MyResponse1 myResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().string(), MyResponse1.class);
                            myResponse.getMessage().getEmail();
                        } else if (json instanceof JSONObject) {

                            MyResponse2 myResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().string(), MyResponse2.class);
                            myResponse.getMessage();
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                // Handle exception here
            }
        });
```

Take two object class for two different response:

// MyResponse1.java

```
public class MyResponse1 {


    private boolean success;
    private MessageBean message;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public MessageBean getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(MessageBean message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static class MessageBean {
        private List<String> email;
        private List<String> password;

        public List<String> getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(List<String> email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public List<String> getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(List<String> password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}
```

// MyResponse2.java

```
public class MyResponse2 {


    private boolean success;
    private String message;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```